# Pass a file to a third party script with fine uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm using Fine Uploader to upload direct to Amazon S3. All is working fine, but I want to use a third party script to access the exif gps data in the image. I've found a script to do it (https://github.com/mattcg/exiflocation.git) which requires a file field in the example script. Is there a way I can pass the local file on to this script using the Fine Uploader API?

Here's my callback script:

```
        onSubmit: function(id, name) {
            var handleFiles, output, URL, revokeObjectUrls, getObjectUrl, objectUrls;

            if (!window.ExifLocation) {
                alert('window.ExifLocation not found. Have you build the example using `make example`?');
                return;
            }
            var exifOutput;
            file=this.getFile(id);
            output = document.getElementById('output');
            console.log(file);
            exifOutput = '';
            ExifLocation.loadFromFile(file, function(err, exifLocation, index) {
                var style, objectUrl;

                if (err) {
                    exifOutput = '<li>' + err + ' (image ' + index + ')</li>';
                } else {
                    latitude= exifLocation.getLatitude().toPrecision(8);
                    longitude = exifLocation.getLongitude().toPrecision(8);
                }
            });
        }
```

Console logging the file outputs a file object.
When I run this I get:
Caught exception in 'onSubmit' callback - undefined is not a function

Any ideas?

Here's the complete error from the console:
[Fine Uploader 5.0.8] Caught exception in 'onSubmit' callback - undefined is not a function
custom.fineuploader-5.0.8.js:212

Comment: What specific line is associated with the error?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply Ray! Have updated with the error above

Comment: You'll need to point at the specific line in your example code above that is failing.  You're using a custom build, so I have no idea what line 212 looks like.  Or, you can look up that line and post it here (with context).

Comment: When you update your question again, please be sure to include the full stack trace along with any line that references your own code.

Comment: It looks like it's this line:
ExifLocation.loadFromFile(file, function(err, exifLocation, index) {
Line 212 in my build is:
                    window.console[level](message);

Comment: Then this is not a Fine Uploader issue.  The error sugests that `ExifLocation` does not contain a function property called `loadFromFile`.

Answer (score 0):

You're quite right Ray - my mistake. It's been a long day! Thanks for your help. The function is called using ExifLocation.prototype.loadFromFile.  Thanks for your help!